# what is 00_png_srz and for what it is used

Tags: html, image, png

Yesterday I saw image with such an extension:  .00_png_srz. First I thought that it was same as normal png image but indeed it isn't. When I renamed it on png it's colors changed. While real one was dark black it became gray.

So I want to know what this extension is used for and what it is exactly. Why would someone create images in such extensions? and is there any way to convert it into normal png without picture changing.

Thanks.

Comment: Attaching a sample might be more useful in order to find out what it is.

Comment: this is template where image is used for http://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/830?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fbusiness-services%2Fcomputing-apps%2F2&bookName=create-master-new&galleryDocIndex=4&category=business-services&metaSiteId=&viewMode=desktop

Comment: but when i download this image http://static.wixstatic.com/media/41d000_17f06ebbb6d3e6b7b83788f3e873d0f1.png_srz_p_275_40_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_png_srz                   it changes color

Comment: The SRZ file extension is associated with DataFlex a relational, 4GL object oriented database programming language and development environment. The *.srz file stores some kind of source data for DataFlex projects.
But never heard with png_srz..

Comment: I don't see the colour changing. Are you sure it is not a perceptual difference in colour?

Also, when I download it, it seems to be a simple .png file that doesn't change colour.

Comment: 41d000_17f06ebbb6d3e6b7b83788f3e873d0f1.png_srz_p_275_40_75_22_0.50_1.20_0 .00_png_srz   this is the name of image and it changes colors. I will send you color codes

Comment: before download_ #333333   and after_ #464646

Comment: Are you using firefox? With firefox it really was simple png but if you will download image with chrome or opera it willhave extension: 00_png_srz. But still color is changing.

Comment: if you want to change the file extension, tried downloading and when it prompts to save, write a name then add let's say: .png to it. i just did that and it worked for me.

Comment: And colors haven't changed?

Comment: The image is turning from dark grey to lighter gray in your viewer.  It appears that your viewer is assuming that it is in a linear colorspace rather than sRGB (actually it's not tagged with any particular colorspace, so the viewer is within its rights to do that).  Specifically, viewers built upon certain ImageMagick versions (I don't remember exactly but it's in the range 6.8.0 to 6.9.0) will do that to grayscale PNGs, but very recently ImageMagick was changed to assume sRGB for all unmarked PNGs.  What are you using to view the image after you download it?